# Sql Server query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a stored procedure on a busy database which constantly come out top in the list of expensive queries (by some way).  The query is very simple, it takes a single parameter (@ID, int) which is the primary key of the table, and selects the record that matches that ID.  The primary key is an identity field with a clustered index, so I am stumped as to how to optimise this any further?

The query is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_Call_Get]

    @ID int = null

AS

    select ID,
        AppID,
        AgentID,
        AgentLogin,
        Ext,
        VDN,
        VDNName,
        Skill,
        SkillName,
        CallFrom,
        TelNoFrom,
        ParentCallID,
        CallStart,
        ACWStart,
        CallEnd,
        Outcome,
        StageID,
        TxTo,
        TxSuccess,
        ServiceID,
        DiallerID,
        CRC,
        TSCallID,
        CallDirection,
        [Manual],
        CallBackAgent,
        CallBackDateTime,
        Notes
    from P_Call
    where (ID = @ID or @ID is null)
```

Not sure the best way to post the execution plan - all it shows is that 100% of the operation is taken up by the clustered index scan

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Can you post the Query and the execution plan?

Comment: when you say it was the most expensive, how many reads was it doing? How often is it called?

Comment: could it be that it appears to be the most expensive due to the high frequency of use? If it's doing 10 logical I/O but running 10,000,000 times a day, it might *look* expensive, but really it's probably fine.

Comment: It is called a lot!  it will be called at least once per agent per call in a call centre with 100 agents taking 3 - 400 calls each per day

Comment: Ok, that is a good point - is there any way to look at the average query cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that by using `where (ID = @ID or @ID is null)` you are getting a sub optimal plan. Divide this into 2 separate queries so that in the case where @Id is not null it will just look it up directly and you will get a seek rather than a scan appear in the plan. You could maybe create a View with the columns you require to avoid the repetition (i.e. the Query without any where clause)

```
select ID,
    AppID,
    AgentID,
    AgentLogin,
    Ext,
    VDN,
    VDNName,
    Skill,
    SkillName,
    CallFrom,
    TelNoFrom,
    ParentCallID,
    CallStart,
    ACWStart,
    CallEnd,
    Outcome,
    StageID,
    TxTo,
    TxSuccess,
    ServiceID,
    DiallerID,
    CRC,
    TSCallID,
    CallDirection,
    [Manual],
    CallBackAgent,
    CallBackDateTime,
    Notes
from P_Call
```

Comment: Splitting into 2 queries did exactly that - I now get a seek rather than a scan in my execution plan.  Which scares me a little as I have used this approach in a number of SPs which search on a number of optional criteria.  Was going to ask about a better approach but I think optimising these is a separate question

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way around the splitting into 2 queries approach. It can be a bit of a pain to keep complex queries in synch though especially if you are using this approach for multiple parameters in the query.

Comment: @Macros There is no way of avoiding the split - SQL server only normally maintains a single execution plan per statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning out procedure cache and memory buffers:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Doing so before testing your procedure's performance will prevent the use of cached execution plans and previous results cache.

Answer (score 0):

can you use table partion. it may fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are in the table? You do realize that a "clustered index scan" = full table scan.

Comment: I didn't...but do now!  have spent the last 2 days optimising SPs based on this

Comment: Good deal. You probably already figured it out why but I should have explained why the optimizer was selecting a sub optimal plan. The reason the index cannot be used is the (or @ID is null) portion of the WHERE clause.  NULL values are not indexed.