# Select all if parameter is null in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, notnull

I want to create a procedure in SQL Server that will select and join two tables. The parameters @company, @from and @to are always set but @serie_type can be NULL. If @serie_type is not NULL i just want to include the specified types, simple `AND S.Type = @serie_type`, but if @serie_type is NULL i want to include all types, simple, just dont include the AND statement. My problem is that i dont know if @serie_type will be set therefore i would like o have something like this:

```
/* pseudocode */
??? = AND (IF @serie_type IS NOT NULL S.Type = @serie_type)
```

Here is a simpifyed version of procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Report_CompanySerie
    @company    INT,
    @serie_type INT,
    @from       DATE,
    @to         DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM Company C
        JOIN Series S ON S.Company_FK = C.Id
    WHERE C.Id = @company 
        AND S.Created >= @from
        AND S.Created <= @to
/* HERE IS MY PROBLEM */        
        AND ???
END
GO
```

Don't want to duplicate the select becaust the real select is way bigger then this.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788391/optimal-search-queries/2788418#2788418

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is **no need to do** `AND  (@serie_type IS NULL OR S.Type = @serie_type)` as SQL Server has a built in function to do this logic for you.

Try this:

```
   .
   .
   AND  S.Type = isnull( @serie_type, S.Type)
```

This returns

true if @serie_type is null or the result of @serie_type = S.Type if  @serie_type is not null.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

> IsNull Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
>
> ```
> ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
> ```
>
> The value of check_expression is returned if it is not NULL;
>   otherwise, replacement_value is returned after it is implicitly
>   converted to the type of check_expression, if the types are different.

Comment: @jeroenh  : looks like you'are wrong, `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )` - "Returns the same type as check_expression."

Comment: @jeroenh - I've edit that answer. You're wrong. I've been using this for years on SQL Server.

Comment: You're absolutely right, learned something new today. Truly sorry

Comment: @Preet Sangha : what you mean saying "no need to do ..."? This is not a hack but ANSI SQL construction, unlike `ISNULL` is T-SQL specific. I'm cqan't understand why "no need to do" sentense, is there any side effects you mean or what? More over, from my point of view condition with `OR` is much cleaner then `ISNULL`

Comment: Hi, I only meant that there is a shorter construction built into SQL server. Ultimately it comes down to choice, and i prefer a less code over more.  If ANSI compliance is a requirement then of course my statement is wrong, but i don'trecall that that was a question requirements.

Answer (score 16):

The common approach is:

```
WHERE 
C.Id = @company          
AND S.Created >= @from         
AND S.Created <= @to 
AND  (@serie_type IS NULL OR S.Type = @serie_type)
```

Comment: Its a perfact answer as check with both side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use case statement in the where clause

where e.ZoneId = case when  @zoneid=0 then e.zoneid else  @zoneid end

Comment: How can I add less than condition instead of "=" in S.Type = ISNULL(@serie_type,S.Type)

Answer (score 0):

The very clean approach will be define your `@serie_type` to be `0`. Take a look below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Report_CompanySerie
    @company    INT,
    @serie_type INT = 0,
    @from       DATE,
    @to         DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM Company C
        JOIN Series S ON S.Company_FK = C.Id
    WHERE C.Id = @company 
        AND S.Created >= @from
        AND S.Created <= @to
/* HERE IS MY PROBLEM */        
        AND (@serie_type = 0 OR S.SerieType = @serie_type)
    END
GO
```