# What does it means that @param IS NULL OR value= @param in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL where i have a scenario that fetch all record if parameter is null or fetch matching record if parameter is not null. In this case, i always use ISNULL function like that:

```
table.value = ISNULL(@param,table.value)
```

But in this case if value is not null, it works fine, but if value is null then it fetch all record except those where table.value is null. So i searched and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513955/select-all-if-parameter-is-null-in-stored-procedure) answered by sII. but i don't understand the statement
 `@param IS NULL OR value= @param` 
It works fine for me but i am unable to understand? How it works? Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: It is a two part statement with a OR... param IS NULL is the first conditional so either this is true or the second conditional value = param is true. What is the issue with it?

Comment: @UsamaZafar there is no issue. I want to know how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my understanding about `ALL IF NULL` Statement.

Case 1: If the parameter `@param` IS `NULL`.

In this case the `All if NULL` statement becomes like this,

```
NULL IS NULL OR value= @param.
```

Here the `left` part of the `OR` statement becomes `True`, So records will fetch according to that part. so the query becomes,

`SELECT *FROM TABLE WHERE NULL IS NULL` which is same as 
`SELECT *FROM TABLE.` So it will fetch all the records.

Case 2: If the parameter `@param` have a value (say value = 1)

In this case the `All if NULL` statement becomes like this,

```
1 IS NULL OR value= 1.
```

Here the `left` part of the `OR` statement becomes `False`, So records will fetch according to the `right` part.
So the query becomes,

```
SELECT *FROM TABLE WHERE value= 1.
```

Hope you understand Now..